# Pymongo vector search

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm trying to perform a vector search using pymongo, here is my index definition:

```
{
 "fields": [
   {
     "numDimensions": 1536,
     "path": "embeddings",
     "similarity": "cosine",
     "type": "vector"
   },
   {
     "path": "company",
     "type": "filter"
   },
   {
     "path": "age",
     "type": "filter"
   }
 ]
}
```

and here is my python code

```py
db.collection.aggregate([
            {
                "$vectorSearch": {
                    "index": "test_index",
                    "path": "embeddings",
                    "queryVector": embeddings,
                    "numCandidates": 100,
                    "limit": 5
                }
            }
        ])
```

When I run this code I get the error: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: embeddings is not indexed as knnVector`

I tried updating the index definition to `"type": "knnVector"` but I'm still getting the same error, any idea of how to solve this issue?